# Change parameter in csv file

Tags: powershell

I want to change the value in TypeAdressage column in my csv if the identifiant is found when it loop  but i dont know how i can do it i try .getTypeAdressage but it's doesn't work

> The CSV:

```
Identifiant;type;Emplacement;TypeAdressage;rack;fabriquant;dateachat
srv4Q5;serveur;Q3506;Statique;R3342;;
PWIN10;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-01-01
Q00032;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-01-01
Q00033;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;LENOVO;2021-01-01
Q00033;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-02-03
```

```
function Changer-Type {
    param(
        [string]$Identifiant,
        [string]$TypeAdressage,
        [string]$Path
    )

    if(-not(Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -or [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path) -ne '.csv') {
        throw 'File doest not exist or is not a Csv...'
    }

    $computers = Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'

    $computers | Where-Object { $_.Identifiant -eq $Identifiant } | ForEach-Object { $_.TypeAdressage = $TypeAdressage }
    #write the updated $computers object array back to disk
    $computers | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Force
}

$csvPath = 'C:\Temp\Peripherique.csv'

Changer-Type -Identifiant "Q00032" -TypeAdressage "Dynamique" -Path $csvPath
```

Comment: PowerShell isn't Java ;-) drop the `get` prefix: `$computers[$i].Identifiant -eq $Identifiant`

Comment: I drop the get but it doesn't change the value of collumn TypeAdressage add index of $i in my CSV file and I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure the CSV has those columns? What does `Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Peripherique.csv" |Get-Member` show?

Comment: i just remove it of the csv files :)

Comment: You never write anything back to the file, so I'm not sure how you're determining whether it works or not? What happens if you add a `$Computers |Export-Csv C:\temp\output.csv` to the end of the function - do you get the expected output in that file then?

Comment: https://ibb.co/wyJsyWL it didnt work in the output.csv

Comment: No idea what's wrong then. Did you remember to remove `get` from `$computers[$i].getTypeAdressage` as well?

Comment: Yep i am jay teamates but i copy your anwser and it doesn't change the value on TypeAdressage in the output csv file

Answer (score 2):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) already commented, you never save anything back to disk..

To find rows where the `Identifiant` is equal to what you send to the function, use a `Where-Object` clause, because looking at the image, there can be multiple rows with the same Identifiant value..

Try

```
function Changer-Type {
    param(
        [string]$Identifiant,
        [string]$TypeAdressage,
        [string]$Path
    )

    if(-not(Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -or [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path) -ne '.csv') {
        throw 'File does not exist or is not a Csv...'
    }

    $computers = Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'

    $computers | Where-Object { $_.Identifiant -eq $Identifiant } | 
                 ForEach-Object { $_.TypeAdressage = $TypeAdressage }
    # write the updated $computers object array back to disk
    $computers | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'  -NoTypeInformation
}

$csvPath = 'C:\Temp\Peripherique.csv'

Changer-Type -Identifiant "Q00032" -TypeAdressage "Dynamique" -Path $csvPath
```

<sup>P.S. I have changed the function name to comply with the PowerShell `Verd-Noun` convention</sup>

Comment: I do but it doesn't change the value on TypeAdressage in the output csv file

Comment: in my tests id does. What character is used as delimiter in the file? Is that not a comma? In that case use parameter `-Delimiter`

Comment: Thanks Theo, but it doesn't change the value in my CSV check the code if it is ok.

code's link: https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/12/94mz.png

CSV image link : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/12/wtzx.png

Comment: You are using a semicolon delimited file. Change to `$computers = Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'` to read the file, and `$computers | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'` to write to the file.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't affect Q00032 TyepAdressage to "Dynamique"

Comment: As @TheMadTechnician said, use `-Delimiter ';'` in your case, but of course also use `-Identifiant "Q00032"` when calling the function.. With that parameter **you** decide which existing ID is to be found. In my example I left out a 0 there. P.S. we could have saved us all these comments if you would have added part of the csv file as Text instead of an image

Comment: The CSV: 
Identifiant;type;Emplacement;TypeAdressage;rack;fabriquant;dateachat
srv4Q5;serveur;Q3506;Statique;R3342;;
PWIN10;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-01-01
Q00032;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-01-01
Q00033;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;LENOVO;2021-01-01
Q00033;ordinateur;Q3507;Statique;;DELL;2020-02-03

Comment: Actually I meant to add the csv in the question where it can be formatted. A comment makes it hard to read. Anyway, I have updated my answer to include the `-Delimiter ';'` and also fixed the missing `0` in parameter `-Identifiant` for you. Please have another go.

Comment: ok I include the CSV in the question. and I try you new answer and it doesn't affect the value in my CSV file

Comment: You don't have the file open in Excel or any other blocking application at the time you run this do you? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no I have no error, I close my excel each time I launch the script  and I have no other applications open

Comment: ..then i'm out of ideas.. Are you sure you're looking at the correct file? It works when I run it..

Comment: Yes I check the right CSV because when this CSV is open power said that he can run it because the CSV file is open

Comment: OK thanks Theo it's finnaly Work have a nice day :)